# Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Graph.GroupMembersCollectionWithReferencesPage' to type 'Microsoft.Graph.Group'

Tags: azure, azure-functions, microsoft-graph-api, group-membership

Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Graph.GroupMembersCollectionWithReferencesPage' to type 'Microsoft.Graph.Group'.

Please give me any solution , I got above error when I try to fetch azure group members by using Microsoft graph API.
I used this namespace (using Group = Microsoft.Graph.Group;)
var members = (Group)teamClient.Groups[itemmembers.Id].Members.Request().GetAsync().Result;

What i need to do to fix it , u need to configure my azure portal settings or i need to modify azure function code

Comment: Can you please check this example to fetch azure group members:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#example-1-get-the-direct-membership-in-a-group

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may be using a TeamClient object instead of a GraphServiceClient object.  This is how to get it with a GraphServiceClient object:

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
var members = await graphClient.Groups["{group-id}"].Members.Request()
    .GetAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```